# " TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable " for excel data

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe

anyone know why it's showed TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable for this code?

```
import pandas as pd

file  = pd.ExcelFile('ReadData.xlsx')
data_ch = file.parse('Sheet1')
idx_ch = data_ch.pop('Tanggal')
data_ch.index = idx_ch

Norm_1 = (data_ch - data_ch.min())/(data_ch.max() - data_ch.min())
Norm_CH = Norm_1.T 
month = 8
date = 31
n=1
m=1
z = date*(month-1)
 for n in range z:
     for m in range date:
            train_ch = Norm_CH(m) + Norm_CH(n) - 1

print (train_ch)
```

i'm using the Excel Data that has String in the first columns

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the error is showing up at the line:

```
Norm_CH(m) + Norm_CH(n) - 1
```

You need to use brackets, not parentheses here:

```
Norm_CH[m] + Norm_CH[n] - 1
```

But there are other issues in you code, you are assigning this to `train_ch`, so only the last value is saved, and then you display another variable, `train`, that is never set.

Comment: thank you for the answer! but right now my code got 
KeyError: 0

Comment: You should try to run this in spyder (or another IDE), and then run each line one by one, with some print calls so that you can debug and understand what is going on.